# How can I create a XML instance with a XSD that includes keyref from another namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, keyref

I am trying to validate a XML instance that depends on another instance (from a different namespace), and it has a keyref to a key in that namespace. When I try to validate the instance, it produces an error that says the key is out of scope.

These are my XSDs:

**test1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="test1" xmlns="test1">

    <xs:complexType name="Host">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="hosts">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="host" type="Host"
                            />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:key name="Host-PK">
                        <xs:selector xpath="host"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xs:key>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**test2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="test2" xmlns="test2" xmlns:t1="test1">

    <xs:import namespace="test1" schemaLocation="test1.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="server">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:keyref name="Host-FK" refer="t1:Host-PK">
            <xs:selector xpath="server"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@host"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And my instances:

**test1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="test1 test1.xsd">
  <hosts>
    <host id="ABC"/>
    <host id="DEF"/>
  </hosts>
</root>
```

**test2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:t1="test1" xmlns="test2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="test2 test2.xsd">
 <server host="ABC"/>
</root>
```

The server host attribute is a key reference to the host ids.

During schema validation the **test2.xml** file raised the error below:

> Error: [Xerces] Identity Constraint error:  the keyref identity
>   constraint "Host-FK" refers to a key or unique that is out of scope.

How can I fix that?

And how can I reference **test1.xml** instance from **test2.xml**?

Comment: Can you change the parent XSD?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can change both XSDs, and that you are using XSD 1.0.

In the first XSD, you will need to qualify your XPath elements, since unprefixed elements belong to *no namespace*. As is your key will not work. You can verify this adding a duplicate ID to `test1`:

```
<root xmlns="test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="test1 test1.xsd">
    <hosts>
        <host id="ABC"/>
        <host id="DEF"/>
        <host id="DEF"/>
    </hosts>
</root>
```

It still validates, when it shouldn't.

To fix that, add a second `test1` namespace declaration with a prefix:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="test1" xmlns="test1" xmlns:t1="test1">
```

Now you can qualify your XPath expression:

```
<xs:key name="Host-PK">
    <xs:selector xpath="t1:host"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:key>
```

And the validation for the duplicate ID will fail, as expected.

Now your second XSD won't be able to find any `Host-PK`. Its `root` element is a completely different one. It just shares the same name with the `root` of `test1`. There's no way it could be in scope. If you want to share the same key in both schemas one thing you could do is to declare the `root` in `test2` as an extension of the `root` in `test1`. But that will require some changes in `test1.xsd` in order to allow `test2` to refer to elements and types in `test1.xsd`.

To allow other schemas to extend the type of the `root` element, make it top-level. Also, make the `hosts` element top-level, since we will need to refer to it in order to define the `keyref`. You can also use it to validate a file which has `hosts` as a root element (this will be useful, as we'll see ahead).

We won't be able to extend `xs:all`, but in your case you can safely replace it with a `xs:sequence`. This is the final **test1.xsd** after refactoring:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="test1" 
           xmlns="test1" 
           xmlns:t1="test1">

    <xs:complexType name="Host">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hosts" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root" type="Root" />

    <xs:element name="hosts">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="host" type="Host"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="Host-PK">
            <xs:selector xpath="t1:host"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I also added `minOccurs="0"` to `hosts` so it will be possible to define a `root` containing only a server (but this is temporary - we will make it required again before we finish)

Now we can refer to the `hosts` element and to the `Root` type in `test2.xsd`. We can start by extending the `root` element's base type, to allow for the `server` element:

```
<xs:complexType name="NewRoot">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="t1:Root">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="server">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

It's also a sequence.

The `root` element should be declared as:

```
<xs:element name="root" type="NewRoot"> ... </xs:element>
```

Now the `root` element in `test2` is an extension of the `root` element in `test1`, and the `host` element will be in context.

Since we have to use XPath to select the server element, it's necessary to declare a prefix for the namespace of `test2` so we can use it in the XPath expression:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:t1="test1" targetNamespace="test2" 
           xmlns="test2" xmlns:t2="test2" >
```

Now you can define a local key that refers to `hosts/host` and use it for the `host` attribute in `server`:

```
<xs:element name="root" type="t2:NewRoot">
    <xs:key name="Host-PK">
        <xs:selector xpath="t1:hosts/t1:host"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="Host-FK" refer="Host-PK">
        <xs:selector xpath="t2:server"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@host"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

And this is your final **test2.xsd** after refactoring:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="test2" 
           xmlns="test2" 
           xmlns:t2="test2" 
           xmlns:t1="test1">

    <xs:import namespace="test1" schemaLocation="test1.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType name="NewRoot">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="t1:Root">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="server">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root" type="t2:NewRoot">
        <xs:key name="Host-PK">
            <xs:selector xpath="t1:hosts/t1:host"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="Host-FK" refer="Host-PK">
            <xs:selector xpath="t2:server"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@host"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So now you try to validate `test2.xml` and ... it fails, but no longer with the "out of scope" error. It fails because it didn't find any key with the `ABC` value. That means it's validating the key all right, but it can't access the `host` elements. You need to have them in your XML instance.

It will work if you simply cut and paste the `hosts` element from the `test1.xml` and set a default namespace for them:

```
<root xmlns:t1="test1" xmlns="test2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="test2 test2.xsd">
    <hosts xmlns="test1">
        <host id="ABC"/>
        <host id="DEF"/>
    </hosts>
    <server host="ABC"/>
</root>
```

You can try it out. It won't validate unless `host` is `ABC` or `DEF`.

You might also want to keep the `hosts` subtree in a separate file, and import it into both your XML instances. The native way to do that is declaring a DTD entity. First place your `hosts` in a file (**test3.xml**):

```
<hosts xmlns="test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="test1 test1.xsd">
    <host id="ABC"/>
    <host id="DEF"/>
</hosts>
```

Now include it into `test1.xml` and `test2.xml` using an `<!ENTITY>`:

**test1.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
   <!ENTITY test3 SYSTEM "test3.xml">
]>

<root xmlns="test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="test1 test1.xsd">
    &test3;
</root>
```

**test2.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
   <!ENTITY test3 SYSTEM "test3.xml">
]>

<root xmlns:t1="test1" xmlns="test2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="test2 test2.xsd">
    &test3;
    <server host="ABC"/>
</root>
```

Now you can place the `minOccurs="0"` back in the declaration for `hosts` in `test1.xsd`, to guarantee that it will always be present.